# What is the fastest way to upload files to Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2016, migration, file

I have more of an admin question - 
we are migrating from local document fileshare to SharePoint 2016 department by department at work .

The last time it took me 5 days to migrate 90 GB with a tool called migration tool which crushed couple of time as well , not so reliable .
Tried syncing as well , that is pretty slow as well. 
So, my questions are:

1. What is the fastest way to upload files (keeping the folder
   structure) to the SharePoint?

Thanks!!

Comment: The simplest way is to create document library in SharePoint site. Open Document library and click on "Open in explorer" button. Copy-paste folders with files.

Answer (score 1):

its depend upon many factors, i.e copying speed on your network, you farm infrastructure etc. As you mentioned you want to move it to SharePoint 2016, i think you have to test couple of methods.

1. RoboCopy: Map the SharePoint document library as map drive then use ropocopy function to move the files to DL.
2. Drag and Drop: In SharePoint 2016 you can use this functionality and simply drag the folders inside SharePoint library.
3. Open with explorer: this option also very help in a lot of scenario but you have to test the speed again.

   [Here is the article](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2016/05/sharepoint-server-2016-dragdrop-performance/) which is telling the story why it is slow in SP 2016. I would also recommend to use the Edge or chrome browser for drag n drop.

Comment: Note that with Drag & drop there is a limit of 100 files per upload batch. It's much more efficient to use option #3 to move large numbers of files, as there is no limit on the number of files you can transfer this way, and you can also copy nested folder structures.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Migration Tool << Be careful with this, its just as slow as the other methods, but when it finished successfully, your files are nowhere. Seen this happen in 3 different companies all were transferring 100GB+
In my opinion, sending a drive to M$ with the data on and asking them to do it is the FASTEST way. Drag and drop via sharepoint is EASIEST way.

-I miss old school ftp :( could easily transfer 400GB in a day, none of this 2 weeks business!!

Answer (score -1):

Try the SharePoint Migration Tool which is used to milk ioloading data to SPO. And it’s free.